# Plotting 2 seaborn KDE joint plots in the same row

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a way to plot two KDE joint plots side by side? I have been able to display almost everyt type of graphs that seaborn can produce using something like this:

```
power_t_series = sDF.pitch
velocity_t_series = sDF.velocity
duration_t_series = sDF.duration

figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
figure.set_size_inches(20,10)
b, g = sns.color_palette("muted", 2)

sns.tsplot(power_t_series, color = b, ax=axes[0])
sns.distplot(power_t_series, color = r, ax=axes[1])
```

But when specifying jointplot, is top-down the only way to display multiple charts of this nature? Here is the code and the error:

```
figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
figure.set_size_inches(20,10)
b, g = sns.color_palette("muted", 2)

sns.jointplot(power_t_series, velocity_t_series, kind='kde', ax=axes[0])
sns.jointplot(power_t_series, duration_t_series, kind='kde', ax=axes[1])
```

I get this:

```
      3 b, g = sns.color_palette("muted", 2)
      4 
----> 5 sns.jointplot(power_t_series, velocity_t_series, kind='kde', ax=axes[0])
      6 sns.jointplot(power_t_series, duration_t_series, kind='kde', ax=axes[1])

TypeError: jointplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ax'
```

Is there any way to plot this type of chart side by side, since ax is not an argument accepted by jointplot()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`jointplot` is a [figure-level function](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html) and can't coexist in a figure with other plots, but there is the `kdeplot` function which can draw a 2-d KDE onto a specific Axes. See [this example](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/cubehelix_palette.html).

Comment: @mwakson oops. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cubehelix_palette' I am using seaborn 0.4.0

Comment: Beautiful example in the link, Mark.  One question for style: why call up the `RandomState` object rather than calling `np.random.randn(2,50)` directly when you got to the point where you needed the two random vectors?

Comment: This lets me seed the random number generator with a specific value so the plot won't change every time I build the docs.

Comment: @LMNYC -- side note: his name's Michael, not Mark.